# automatically insert '...' at the end when text is too large to display in one line in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, automatic-updates

I want to insert '...' string at the end of label if inner text is too large to display in one line.
Now. It displays 'this is my shcool tea'
I want to change 'tea' to '...' automatically. is there any function in python?

```
  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        lable = QLabel(self)
        lable.setText('this is my school teacher')

    def enterEvent(self,event):

        pass
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        self.calc()
    def calc(self):

        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Important is to deal with several font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could set a limit for the string length, like `limit=10`
Then you could check if the string exceeds the limit

```py
if len(text)>limit:
    text=text[:limit]+"..."
```

Then you could set the label in `__init__`:

```
label.setText(text)
```

Comment: I want to deal with several font